# How to calculate Median in Excel if multiple criteria (Date, Name, Days Open,Level) are selected

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to calculate the median Days Open time for items within an excel worksheet. Data looks like this...

The Data contains weeks ending such as 4/22, 4/29, 5/6 and so on, 'Days Open' ranging 1-20 random values, and Levels of High Medium Low.

The output graph has the dates on the X-Axis with 3 columns for high medium low and the y axis is Median days open.

originally it was an average so I had this

```
IF(F47=0,0,AVERAGEIFS(Data_!$AF:$AF,Data_!$AC:$AC,N$42,Data_!$D:$D,VLOOKUP($J47,Ref!$X$1:$Y$5,2,0)))
```

for the median I've tried

```
=MEDIAN(IF((Data_!$AC:$AC=K$43)*(Data_!D:D=$J45),Data_!AF:AF,""))
```

Where Column AC is for the dates, Column D is for the Level and Column AF is Days open

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.